# How import xml files with mysql LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, xml

I have a xml file like this:

> test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<plugin name="tree">
    <title>Test</title>
    <description>some description</description>
    <files>
        <file>test.tmp</file>
    </files>
    <install><![CDATA[
        global $test;
    ]]></install>
    <hooks>
        <hook name="hookname"><![CDATA[
            global $local;
        ]]></hook>
    </hooks>

    <phrases>
        <phrase key="category"><![CDATA[Show categories]]></phrase>
    </phrases>
</plugin>
```

and i like to import it into a MySQL Table like 'mytable'

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (plugin varchar(255),title varchar(255),description varchar(255), file varchar(255),install varchar(255),hook varchar(255),phrase varchar(255));
```

I used below command

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'test.xml' 
INTO TABLE mytable(plugin,title,description,file,install,hook,phrase);
```

it runs successfully but with 0 rows!

> The query has been successfully implemented, 0 rows have been
>   affected.

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Include this line `ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<plugin>'`. with that your query should look like

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE "D:\\test.xml"
INTO TABLE mytable
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<plugin>';
```

Looks like your XML file formation is not correct and so even though 1 row gets inserted; all the values doesn't gets extracted (remains `NULL`).

Do little changes as below

Create table structure

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
plugin_name varchar(255),
title varchar(255),
description varchar(255), 
`file` varchar(255),
`install` varchar(255),
hook varchar(255),
phrase varchar(255));
```

Change your XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<plugin plugin_name="tree">
    <title>Test</title>
    <description>some description</description>
         <file>test.tmp</file>
    <install>![CDATA[
        global $test;
    ]]</install>
        <hook name="hookname">![CDATA[
            global $local;
        ]]</hook>
        <phrase key="category">![CDATA[Show categories]]</phrase>
</plugin>
```

Now if you use

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE "D:\\test.xml"
INTO TABLE mytable
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<plugin>';
```

All data gets extracted fine

[image]

Comment: what if you cant change the xml file?

Comment: The xml file HAS to be in one of the three forms described, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html

Comment: Also, SHOW WARNINGS executed right after the attempted import may shed light on problems encountered.

Comment: As a word of caution on latest MariaDB:
Exporting XML took about 5 minutes.
Importing again takes 48 hours.

The xml implementation is garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the answer given above; I just wanted to add that the database fields character casing must be same as that of the XML field casing. Or else load XML wouldn't be able to import that specific column(s).