# Importing XML to MySQL relational tables

Tags: mysql, xml, relational-database

I am trying to import XML into an SQL database, however I am having issues importing sub-elements into the SQL server

```
<bug>
  <bug_id>925710</bug_id>

  <creation_ts>2013-10-11 05:24:10 -0700</creation_ts>
  <short_desc>Update conditionalForwardWithUrlbarWidth to reflect reality</short_desc>
  <classification>Client Software</classification>
  <product>Firefox</product>
  <component>Theme</component>
  <version>Trunk</version>
  <rep_platform>All</rep_platform>
  <op_sys>Linux</op_sys>
  <bug_status>RESOLVED</bug_status>
  <resolution>FIXED</resolution>

  <long_desc isprivate="0">
    <commentid>7949860</commentid>
    <attachid>815815</attachid>
    <who name="Dão Gottwald [:dao]">dao</who>
    <bug_when>2013-10-11 05:24:10 -0700</bug_when>
    <thetext>Created attachment 815815 patch . The forward icon is now 18 instead of 24 pixels wide.</thetext>
  </long_desc>

  <long_desc isprivate="0">
    <commentid>7950323</commentid>
    <who name="Dão Gottwald [:dao]">dao</who>
    <bug_when>2013-10-11 08:04:54 -0700</bug_when>
    <thetext>http://hg.mozilla.org/projects/ux/rev/f0b25f2217ab</thetext>
  </long_desc>

  <long_desc isprivate="0">
    <commentid>8092710</commentid>
    <who name=":Gijs Kruitbosch">gijskruitbosch+bugs</who>
    <bug_when>2013-11-18 12:39:15 -0800</bug_when>
    <thetext>https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/f0b25f2217ab</thetext>
  </long_desc>
</bug>
```

I am importing the XML into the SQL database using

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE "D:\\test.xml"
INTO TABLE mytable
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<bug>';
```

However I cannot figure out a way to create a relational table which references the bug_id's to the comments, as when I use

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE "D:\\test.xml"
INTO TABLE mytable
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<long_desc>';
```

The bug_id obviously cannot be accessed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932102/how-import-xml-files-with-mysql-load-xml-local-infile

Comment: I cannot change the style and format of the XML file, like that answer suggests

Comment: Have a look at the documentation, might help - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-xml.html

Comment: If you want to do this from mysql, then I think you need to use compiled user defined functions, since load xml statement will not populate a whole hierarchy of tables for you, and load xml cannot be called from stored procedures. It may be easier to do this from an outside application.