# How insert special characters using mysql insert?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xslt

I am new in MYSQL, I have a XML file of hotels, that include HotelCode and Description of hotel. Xml file like below

```
<hotels>
        <hotel>
        <hotelcode>1</hotelcode>
        <description>San cassiano residenzia D’epocaVenice’s Grand Canal.Overview Situated overlooking Venice’s Grand Canal, San Cassiano Residenzia D’Epoca is a historic hotel with plenty of charm</description>
        </hotel>
<hotel>
        <hotelcode>2</hotelcode>
        <description>San cassiano residenzia D’epocaVenice’s Grand Canal.Overview Situated overlooking Venice’s Grand Canal, San Cassiano Residenzia D’Epoca is a historic hotel with plenty of charm</description>
        </hotel>
<hotel>
        <hotelcode>3</hotelcode>
        <description>San cassiano residenzia D’epocaVenice’s Grand Canal.Overview Situated overlooking Venice’s Grand Canal, San Cassiano Residenzia D’Epoca is a historic hotel with plenty of charm</description>
        </hotel>
    <hotels>
```

Also i using below sql query to insert xml data to database

```
$conn_1->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$rs_file_path."'
            INTO TABLE hotels
            CHARACTER SET utf8
            LINES STARTING BY '<hotel>' TERMINATED BY '</hotel>'
            (@tmp)
            SET
                hotelcode = ExtractValue(@tmp, 'hotelcode'),
                description= ExtractValue(@tmp, 'description')

            ;");
```

But here data's are not insert to hotels table. because description includes some special characters like ',"", etc.

There is any way some thing like `mysqli_real_escape_string`

**update:**
"But now i identify that quotes comes in the xml two types like below picture"
[image]

How to replace the second type of quotes?

please check the attached file.

```html
 <hotels>
            <hotel>
            <hotelcode>1</hotelcode>
            <description>Located near S'Arenal Venice’s yacht club</description>
            </hotel>
<hotel>
            <hotelcode>2</hotelcode>
            <description>Located near S'Arenal Venice’s yacht club</description>
            </hotel>
<hotel>
            <hotelcode>3</hotelcode>
            <description>Located near S'Arenal Venice’s yacht club</description>
            </hotel>
</hotels>
```

Comment: Have you considered using LOAD XML rather than LOAD DATA? I don't have any experience with it to be honest, but it seems like it would work better for XML.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932102/how-import-xml-files-with-mysql-load-xml-local-infile

Comment: i update the question

Comment: You are still not using [`LOAD XML`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-xml.html) which makes import very easy with your flat XML.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd quote character is the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`&rsquo;`  `&#8217;` `U+2019`).

If using XSLT, you can replace it using the `translate()` function, e.g.:

```
<xsl:value-of select='translate(description, "&#8217;", "&apos;")'/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$content = file($rs_file_path);
$filedata = str_replace("'", "\'", $content);
$filedata = str_replace('"', '\"', $content);
$conn_1->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$rs_file_path."'
        INTO TABLE hotels
        CHARACTER SET utf8
        LINES STARTING BY '<hotel>' TERMINATED BY '</hotel>'
        (@tmp)
        SET
            hotelcode = ExtractValue(@tmp, 'hotelcode'),
            description= ExtractValue(@tmp, 'description')

        ;");
```

It will open your file and add slashes at the single quotes and double quotes.

When You retrieve table data Use like this to prevent slashes to be print

```
echo stripslashes($str);
```

Comment: thank you for the replay, but i update the question